# What is the reason for the Java DataBuffer class?

Tags: java, swing, awt, bufferedimage

When I was about to investigate the internal implementation of the [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) class in Java, I came across the [DataBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html). The DataBuffer is in finally used to save the blank image data, which can only be interpreted with the related [ColorModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html) and [SampleModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/SampleModel.html) implementation. However, I do not understand the real purpose of the DataBuffer beside of the fact, that it wraps arrays of the same type with some read and write helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataBuffer` is an abstraction, so that `BufferedImage` does not need to know about actual pixel storage.

Pixels are *usually* stored in arrays, but it can be a single packed or interleaved array, or it can be a single or multiple banded arrays. Multiply that with the number of transfer types supported, and you will see there's a lot of different cases to handle. It makes a lot of sense to delegate this to specialized  implementations,  and avoid having knowledge about all these different types in `BufferedImage` itself.

But it doesn't even have to be an array at all. As an example, I have successfully implemented `DataBuffer`s backed by nio `ByteBuffer`s and memory mapped files.